# How to add a pop up with Plotly Dash

Tags: python, download, callback, popup, plotly-dash

Does anyone know if there's a way to trigger a pop -up once a file is created?

I think it will need to be done with a call back.  I have a working app, I just want this message "your file is ready to download!" triggered once the file is created.

This is so the user knows when to click the download button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're creating the file in your app then after you create the file just have the callback return a popup box, something like:

```py
@callback(
    Output('popupbox-wrapper', 'display'),
    Input('create-file-button', 'n_clicks')
)
def update_network_data_cb(create_file):
    ...
    # create file
    ...
    return html.Div(['File created!', html.Button('OK', id='close-popup')])
```

Then handle the `close-popup` button by hiding it after being clicked.

If you don't know when the file will be created then you can set up a callback to trigger on an [interval](https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates) and check if the file exists yet. Once it exists return the popup just as stated above.